# Симуляция вентильной логики в Multisim

Tags: логика

Почему при симуляции цифровой (вентильной) логики со сдвиговым регистром типа PISO (любым), "теряется" при  выходе первый бит? Подобное поведение также и показывает и TINA!

Comment: У вас код какой-то есть для иллюстрации проблемы? Если есть, то добавьте его прямо в вопрос.